# reactjs : How to set a default value by specific value in react-select?

Tags: reactjs

First, let me say that I searched a lot about the problem, but I could not solve my problem.

I have a specific value that I want to be displayed in the view in the select box by default.

select code :

```
<Select
      options={getMainCategory.data.map((item) => {
        return { value: item.id, label: item.categoryName };
      })}
       defaultValue={getMainCategory.data.find((x)=>{
        const c = x.id === mainparentId;
        return { value: c.id, label: c.categoryName };
       })}
      onChange={onOptionChange}
/>
```

I did it with the above code but it didn't work. I would be grateful if you could guide me?

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is you are using `defaultValue` function, which must be `string`, `number`, `object`. In your example you have to use `value` property as following:

```
<Select
  options={getMainCategory.data.map((item) => {
    return { value: item.id, label: item.categoryName };
  })}
  defaultValue={getMainCategory.data.find((x) => x.id === mainparentId).value}
  onChange={onOptionChange}
/>
```

Comment: Nothing was displayed